# Does Haptic works in SpriteKit in watchOS 3?

Tags: sprite-kit, watchos, watchos-3

If I am not using SpriteKit, this works in watchOS, and I can feel the slight vibration.

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.click)
```

But if I am using this in SpriteKit, says:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    ...
    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.click)
}
```

It does not work, no click sound, no haptic feedback. I also tried other WKHapticType and the result is the same. Any idea?

Comment: silly question, are you importing the frameworks you need for vibration in your Swift project?

Comment: If you do not import the framework, can this even compile?

Comment: This may be bounty worthy as haptics are key to unique watchOS games. I will be following this